# Laravel/Eloquent : Multiple conditional clauses in request

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am trying to put multiple conditional clauses on my request, but i get this error: Where is my mistake in my query ?

```
    (1/1) ErrorException
mb_strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given
```

Code:

```
$data = Ov::with([
            'ovLicenses',
            'masters' => function ($query) use ($devicesArrayOnlyLKUAToZero) {
                $query->whereIn('macAddress', $devicesArrayOnlyLKUAToZero);
            }, function ($query) {
                $query->orWhere('lastKnownUpAt','<>', '0');
            },
            'masters.licenses',
            'masters.equipment',
            'masters.slaveEquipments.equipment',
            'wireless'=> function ($query) use ($devicesArrayOnlyLKUAToZero) {
                $query->whereIn('macAddress', $devicesArrayOnlyLKUAToZero);
            }, function ($query) {
                $query->orWhere('lastKnownUpAt','<>', '0');
            },
            'wireless.licenses',
            'wireless.equipment'
        ])->where('ovId', '=', $ovId)->get();
```

Comment: you missed a comma after function ($query) {
                $query->orWhere('lastKnownUpAt','<>', '0');
            }

Comment: @pseudoanime Yes, thanks. I updated my post because i always get an error

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you are not using

```
$data = Ov::with([
            'ovLicenses',
            'masters' => function ($query) use ($devicesArrayOnlyLKUAToZero) {
                $query->whereIn('macAddress', $devicesArrayOnlyLKUAToZero)
                      ->orWhere('lastKnownUpAt','<>', '0');
            },
            'masters.licenses',
            'masters.equipment',
            'masters.slaveEquipments.equipment',
            'wireless'=> function ($query) use ($devicesArrayOnlyLKUAToZero) {
                $query->whereIn('macAddress', $devicesArrayOnlyLKUAToZero)
                      ->orWhere('lastKnownUpAt','<>', '0');
            },
            'wireless.licenses',
            'wireless.equipment'
        ])->where('ovId', '=', $ovId)->get();
```

Comment: I made exaclty this code before, but i have a problem with this piece of code: When i apply the orWhere statement, it returns the full list of masters even masters which doesn't correspond to the where(ovId..) clauses at the bottom. How can i do to be sure to return the list of masters where macAddress is contained into the used deviceArray AND where lastKnownUpAt is different than 0?

Comment: Moreover, when i do this code, sometimes i get a memory exceeded error. (due to that i explain before with the orWhere close which load all masters without applying the where clause in bottom)